# Как отсортировать COUNT() из другой таблицы mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Очень неожиданно возникла проблема с нехваткой знаний в sql(mysql). Времени их пополнить нет. 
Есть задача сделать рейтинг по кол-во открытых кейсов, пользователем (сайт-рулетка). Каждое открытие кейса храниться в таблице history и имеет ключ пользователя, который открыл данный кейс. В таблице user каждому пользователю так же присвоен уникальный ключ (что то типа id). Я могу без проблем получить COUNT() открытых кейсов. НО!
Как мне получить топ (10,20,30,...) пользователей по открытым кейсам, используя инструменты mysql?
Так же можете направить на необходимую документацию по теме.

Comment: А что такое топ по открытым кейсам ? количество по каждому пользователю ? тогда просто group by по id пользователя

Comment: А таблицу с именами пользователей, если они нужны, join'инить уже после группировки к подзапросу

Comment: *Как мне получить топ (10,20,30,...) пользователей по открытым кейсам, используя инструменты mysql?* Использовать правильную сортировку результата. И LIMIT для ограничения количества записей.

Comment: @Mike можешь подсказать как  _join'инить уже после группировки._ После группировки  выдает ошибку, а если до... крч уже час пытаюсь разобраться, все никак не поддается =(

Comment: `select ... from (select user_id, count(1) as cnt from tab group by user_id) x join users u on u.id=x.user_id`

Comment: @Mike 
Знаю, уже надоел наверное, но как вывести еще и кол-во открытых кейсов `COUNT(*)` сейчас только логины.

`$mysql_q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT login
                                FROM (SELECT key_valid, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM history_case GROUP BY key_valid) AS x
                                JOIN user AS u ON (u.key_valid = x.key_valid)
                                ORDER BY cnt DESC
                                LIMIT $limit
                                ");`
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А что такое "открытые кейсы" ? где они хранятся и чем отличаются от "не открытых' например

Comment: @Mike они хранятся в таблице `history_case`, в виде записи. Не открытых не может быть, так как запись создается только после открытия. Она содержит даты, выигрыш и ключ пользователя, `key_valid`.
`SELECT key_valid, COUNT(*) AS opens
                                FROM history_case
                                GROUP BY key_valid
                                ORDER BY opens DESC
                                LIMIT $limit`
Данный запрос выводит кол-во открытых кейсов, запрос, который выше в комментарии, логины, как объединить их?

Comment: т.е. у вас во внутреннем запросе как раз получаются нужные количества ? так и выводите их рядом с логином `select login, cnt from ...`

Comment: @Mike Благодарю! Вы святой человек =)

Answer (score 0):

Вот нужный мне запрос.

```
"SELECT login, cnt
 FROM (SELECT key_valid, COUNT(*) AS cnt
       FROM history_case
       GROUP BY key_valid) AS x
 JOIN user AS u ON (u.key_valid = x.key_valid)
 ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT $limit"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Так вывести топ-10 пользователей (user) по открытым кейсам (cases):

```
SELECT name, open_cases
  FROM (
    SELECT key, COUNT(*) AS open_cases
      FROM cases
     GROUP BY key) AS c
 JOIN user AS u ON (u.key = q.key)
 ORDER BY open_cases DESC LIMIT 10;
```